# Suggestion for API Documentation in confluence?

Tags: documentation, confluence

We already have Confluence in place for documenting software products.

Does anyone have any recommendations on the best approach for API Documentation?

E.g. User Confluence with a Swagger plugin to show API Documentation on a page?

Answer (score 1):

You can try some already existing 3-rd party addons like:

1. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219386/open-api-swagger-integration?hosting=cloud&tab=overview
2. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220747/swagger-ui-for-confluence?hosting=cloud&tab=overview
   You can check the documentation for each addon on its page, but the main point is to set the Swager (Open API) file location you have and it will be generated in Confluence.

Another approach is to write the documentation on Confluence pages yourself using the pages editor and all the macros you need to create the dynamic documentation and export it to Word or reuse it as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [RapiDoc mini](https://rapidocweb.com/rapidoc-mini.html), an embeddable version of [RapiDoc](https://rapidocweb.com/index.html).

The best things about it compared to ugly plugins for Confluence are speed, full visual and functional customization, ability to refer both local and remote API specifications, and filtering of endpoints via plain text or regular expression.

To quickstart, add the following code to HTML macro in Confluence:

```html
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/rapidoc/dist/rapidoc-min.js"></script>
<rapi-doc-mini
  spec-url = "https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json"
  style= "min-width:600px;"
  paths-expanded = "false"
  theme = "light"
  allow-authentication=false
  allow-server-selection=false
  allow-try=false
> </rapi-doc-mini>
```

The resulting page will look like this:

[image: Embedded RapiDoc mini]